# 'CGPathGetBoundingBox' has been replaced by property 'CGPath.boundingBox'

Tags: ios, swift, cgpath

I am integrating a library which was written in early `Swift`. Since a compatible version of that library with *Swift 4* is not available, I was removing the errors myself.
There is this line :

```
let pathBounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path.cgPath);
```

which is giving the error :

> 'CGPathGetBoundingBox' has been replaced by property
>   'CGPath.boundingBox'

along with the warning :

> 'CGPathGetBoundingBox' was obsoleted in Swift 3
>   (CoreGraphics.CGPathGetBoundingBox)

What is it's replacement in *Swift 4* ? There is a function `boundingBox` in `CGPath` class but I am not able to figure out how to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple :

`path.cgPath.boundingBox`

Comment: swift 5: path.boundingBox